# How do I set the linesize to -1?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have two computers with different preferences for sql developer and sqlplus.  I'm trying to make them equivalent.  When I say `show linesize` on one, it returns `-1`.  But if I `set linesize -1` on the other, it returns an error saying that it's not a valid option:

```
SP2-0268: linesize option not a valid number
```

How do I set the linesize to -1?  I prefer this value because it seems to not wrap.

Answer (score 0):

It's certain that on `sqlplus` you cannot set line size to -1 because the range itself is from `1` through `32767`.

```
SQL> set linesize -1
SP2-0267: linesize option -1 out of range (1 through 32767)
```

Comment: Unclear about this as an *answer*.  Seems to have the same information I already provided in the question.

Comment: I just wanted to say that you cannot set linesize to -1  in sqlplus. It just doesnot allow.

Comment: Does it make sense that `show linesize` would return `-1`?  Is there a way to unset `linesize`?

Comment: Am not  sure about sql developer but certainly in sqlplus it doesnot make any sense. I would say you do show linesize in sqlplus and try to set the same in sql developer..